# Beamer: title-page full page image

Tags: beamer, presentations

I need to create a full-slide image as the first and final slides, as well as having a separate theme for the title page.

I've been given the first/last slides, the title page and the generic slides as `.jpg` files. They're called `firstpage.jpg`, `titlepage.jpg`, `slide.png` respectively.

So far I can create the generic slide with this sty file (`beamerinnerthemecdt.sty`):

```
\mode<presentation>

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{\begin{tikzpicture}\node[opacity=.9]
{\includegraphics [width=\paperwidth]{slide.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}}

% Title page
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{cdt}[1][]
{ \begin{tikzpicture}
  \titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{titlepage.jpg}}
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\mode
<all>
```

My colour theme is:

```
\mode<presentation>

% Settings
\setbeamercolor*{title page header}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{author}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{date}{fg=white}

\mode
<all>
```

and my outer theme is:

```
\mode<presentation>

% Frame title
\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{texsx}[1][]
{
\vskip1cm%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=1.2cm]{frametitle} 

 \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\mode<all>
```

Here is an example presentation file:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\title{There Is No Largest Prime Number}
\date[ISPN ’80]{27th International Symposium of Prime Numbers}
\author[Euclid]{Euclid of Alexandria \texttt{euclid@alexandria.edu}}

\usetheme{cdt}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame} 
\frametitle{There Is No Largest Prime Number} 
\framesubtitle{The proof uses \textit{reductio ad absurdum}.} 
\begin{theorem}
There is no largest prime number. \end{theorem} 
\begin{enumerate} 
\item<1-| alert@1> Suppose $p$ were the largest prime number. 
\item<2-> Let $q$ be the product of the first $p$ numbers. 
\item<3-> Then $q+1$ is not divisible by any of them. 
\item<1-> But $q + 1$ is greater than $1$, thus divisible by some prime
number not in the first $p$ numbers.
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

This seems to work ok, but I can't get beamer to add the other slides as well.

How would I go about defining the `.sty` files so that I had a first page, title page, generic slide and final (same as first) page slides. I.e. how do I get beamer to accept these images as backgrounds for the appropriate slide?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I've added an example file, but I'm not sure that'll help.

Comment: Try this:
`\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
      \node at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{YUR_IMG}};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
  \end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: @s__C in the defbeamertemplate in the inner theme?

Comment: @TomKealy if you want this image to appear on each frame... else just in the specific frame you want. Plus you may need to play with `width` + `height` (and also add `\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}` in your preamble)

Comment: No, I want a specific image to appear on the first and last frame. I can make the slide.jpg image appear as a background on every frame at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following minimal working example shows how you can include arbitrary background images on any frame within your presentation.

This code tells LaTeX to include the figure `default.jpg` as the background for every frame except those for which you specify a different background. The below code produces a document of five slides with the following background images:

(1) `picture1.jpg`; (2) `default.jpg`; (3) `default.jpg`; (4) `picture2.jpg`; (5) no bckground image.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{default.jpg}}
\begin{document}


{
\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{picture1.jpg}}
\begin{frame}
  [...]
\end{frame}
}


\begin{frame}
  [...]
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
  [...]
\end{frame}


{
\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{picture2.jpg}}
\begin{frame}
  [...]
\end{frame}
}


{
\usebackgroundtemplate{}
\begin{frame}
  [...]
\end{frame}
}
\end{document}
```

Replace the `[...]` with whatever content you want on the frame and LaTeX will simply overlay that content on top of the background image. Alternatively, if you want to produce a slide with only the background image and no other content, you can simply make an empty frame:

```
{
\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{picture.jpg}}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
}
```